# Using IF AND statement in Excel formula doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Image 1]

Hello All,

I've alter question in simpler way.

Right now I'm working on image where Col A & B has some values. I've to find values in Col C, where if Col A values "No Windows" & Col B values "No SQL".

I've used formula of IF AND statement in Col C. The Col C will represent it as "Yes" where Col A values "No Windows" & Col B values "No SQL" else formula will reflect it as "no".

For reference: In Col D represent the actual result needed after formula is applied.

Formula used : IF AND statement in Excel

```
=IF(AND(A2="No Windows",B2="No SQL"),"Yes","no")
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you mean if "No Windows" is in column A and something other than "No SQL" is in column B you want to delete the entries, or copy them somewhere and then delete?

Comment: @SJR I've alter question.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are leading or trailing spaces? Try trim(a2) and trim(b2) in the and()...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah Trim worked.

Comment: Glad it helped - had that issue myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So sometimes the data tested has leading or trailing spaces, try using trim() like this:

```
=IF(AND(trim(A2)="No Windows",trim(B2)="No SQL"),"Yes","no")
```